# numpy update array indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have following indices

```
indices = array([[ 0,  0],
   [ 1,  1],
   [ 5,  3],
   [ 7,  9]])
```

I want to update a 2d numpy array with these indices as one

```
img = np.zeros((12,12), np.uint8)
```

I tried the following

```
img[indices] = 1
indices_x = indices[:, 0]
indices_y = indices[:, 1]
img[np.ix_(indices_x,indices_y)] = 1
```

Comment: Like this `img[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]] = 1`

Comment: Thanks coldspeed. Cannot upvote because of low reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the x and y indices separately.

```
In [0]: img[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]] = 3

In [1]: img
Out[1]: 
array([[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Alternatively, you can give a tuple or list:

```
In [2]: new_inds = tuple(zip(*indices))

In [3]: new_inds
Out[3]: ((0, 1, 5, 7), (0, 1, 3, 9))

In [4]: img[new_inds] = 4

In [5]: img
Out[5]: 
array([[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: One of these things is not like the other.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. Cannot upvote because of low reputation